# Polynomials with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, variables, calculation, polynomials

I am trying to write Bernstein polynomial on python, but I have a problem with poly1d function. In Bernstein function the variable is **t**, but in poly1d function default variable is **x**. In the following codes I call variable as **t**:

```
1: print((nCr(2, 0)*((np.poly1d([1, 0], variable="t"))**0)*((np.poly1d([-1, 1], variable="t"))**(2-0))))

2: print(np.poly1d([-1, 1], variable="t"))
```

But I got outputs like that:

```
1: 1 x^2 - 2 x + 1
 
2: -1 t + 1
```

How can I solve my problem for the first one?

Answer (score 1):

`np.poly1d()` provides a `variable` argument just for printing purposes. It doesn't actually use it in operations.

For example:

```
>>> vars(np.poly1d([1, 2], variable='t'))
{'coeffs': array([1, 2]), '_variable': 't'}

# but:
>>> vars(1 * np.poly1d([1, 2], variable='t'))
{'coeffs': array([1, 2]), '_variable': 'x'}
```

So, I would recommend adding the `variable` bit as a last step:

```
pol = np.poly1d((nCr(2, 0) * ((np.poly1d([1, 0]))**0)*((np.poly1d([-1, 1]))**(2-0))), variable='t')
print(pol)
# out:
   2
1 t - 2 t + 1
```